# take contents of a file and search those in all the files in a particular directory in unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Suppose I have a file named result with some contents like:-

```
column_a column_b column_c
888888   854254   412589
777777   458754   863324
```

I want to search for contents of only column_a and column_b in all the text files in this particular directory. suppose this directory contains 100 text files. I want to search column_a and column_b of result file in all the directories and print them on the screen with the name of the file where the particular string is present.

Like 888888 is present in file1 file4 file77 out of 100 files.

Comment: Could you post a file sample and the desired output ? What have you tried so far ? The way I understand it, it sounds like it could be done with a simple `grep` over all the files in the pwd

Comment: paste your code snippet here, people will help you to improve it further

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` and `awk`:

```
find dir -type f -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -print0 | xargs -0 -d '\n' -- \
    awk -v s='888888' '$1 == s || $2 == s { printf "%s is in %s.\n", s, FILENAME; nextfile }'
```

`-maxdepth 1` or `-mindepth 1` is optional.

`nextfile` is an extension of GNU awk. If you're not using GNU awk, you can do this instead:

```
    awk -v s='888888' '($1 == s || $2 == s) && !a[FILENAME]++ { printf "%s is in %s.\n", s, FILENAME }'
```

Answer (score 0):

First, modify the results file to make it more usable:

```
awk 'NR>1{printf "%s\n%s\n", $1, $2}' result > tmp
```

Then use grep to find the files that match:

```
grep -w -l -f tmp *
```